# Convertir a excel data only a determinada hora

Tags: excel, vba, phpexcel, vb6

En una carpeta de mi equipo recibo diariamente un archivo de excel 2003-2007 standard , por ejemplo lo recibo a las 11:00 am . Necesito a las 11:05 am convertir ese mismo archivo a excel 2003-2007 Data-Only  ( formato al cual exporta crystal reports ) . Hay alguna aplicación free que me permita automatizar esto o de que forma me pueden recomendar investigar ? Manejo algo de vb6, php y sino puedo aprender. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guardar como. O sino, alguna web como https://www.zamzar.com/convert/xlsx-to-Excel/ te pueden servir?

Comment: Ok muchas gracias